# «Прежде, чем что-то( , / – ) нужно что-то»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, тире, союзы, спп

Необходимо ли ставить запятую или тире в предложении: "Прежде чем играть( , / – ) необходимо настроить инструмент"?

Спасибо!

Comment: *Arsenii*, какой именно знак и в каком именно месте Вас интересует? В шапке: *Прежде, чем...* В тексте вопроса: *Прежде чем играть(,)(-)...* И — желательно представить свое собственное решение (или предположение).

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова исправил шапку. Варианты в тексте в скобках. Спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Конечно, **запятая** после придаточного предложения с союзом «[прежде чем](http://new.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum?layout=item&id=58_628)» необходима и абсолютно соответствует грамматическим правилам и частотности использования.

*Прежде чем играть, необходимо настроить инструмент.*

Постановка **тире** не исключена:

*Прежде чем играть – необходимо настроить инструмент.*

[Тире в сложноподчиненном предложении](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=142)

> 1. **Тире** ставится для интонационного отделения главной части сложноподчиненного предложения от придаточной. Чаще всего тире употребляется в тех случаях, когда главной части предшествует...

И далее идёт перечисление, где нет подходящего случая, но ведь главное в том, что это правило основано на интонационном принципе. В нём приводятся примеры, в которых используется тире "**чаще всего**", а значит, не только в них.

*Во всяком случае, прежде чем верить ― нужно спросить* (Л. И. Шестов. На весах Иова. 1929).
*Прежде чем говорить ― обязательно подумать!!!* (Нелли К. Дневник. 1986).
*Господа, прежде чем писать или давать советы ― отработайте в нашей системе* (Форум: Ресторанный бизнес. Как открыть ресторан. 2008-2013).

Comment: Благодарю Вас, Александр! Наболевшие вопросы!